# "IndexError: list index out of range" when swapping elements in a list

Tags: python, list, indexing, index-error

I have to write a function 'swaplist' which does the following:

given in input 2 lists:

list1, list2

such as:

[s4,s6]

[4,2,3,6,5]

*keep in mind [s5] can't be given in input

returns a list in which 4 is swapped with the next number and 6 is swapped with the next number

[2,4,3,5,6]

This is the code i wrote:

```
def swaplist(list1,list2):
    list3=list2
    for i in list3:
        if ('s'+str(i)) in list1:
            a=list3.index(i)
            b=a+1
            list3[a],list3[b]=list3[b],list3[a]
    return list3
```

I tried running this code and i got the following error:

`IndexError: list index out of range`

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks guys for your time

- and sorry for my broken english

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the list while iterating over it which will result in unwanted behaviour.

If we do a `print(list3)` for each time we swap a number, we can see what happens to the list while looping.

After inspecting the first number in the list, we see that it is a 4, which should be swapped. The list was `[4, 2, 3, 5, 6]` and is now `[2, 4, 3, 5, 6]`.

Let's move onto the second number in the list. Because you modified the original list, the second number is now 4, which will be swapped with the next number.

This is what the program prints after each swap:

```
[2, 4, 3, 5, 6]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[2, 3, 5, 4, 6]
[2, 3, 5, 6, 4]
```

Your number four is being moved along to the next place in the list, after which it is inspected again.

The way to solve this, is to construct a new list, and not modify the original list. Something like this:

```
def swaplist(list1,list2):
    # Make a copy of the original list so we don't modify it.
    # Use a more verbose name for the list so it's clear what the purpose is
    result_list=list2.copy()

    # Use enumerate to get both the index (i), as well as the list item in one go.
    for i, item in enumerate(list2):
        if ('s'+str(item)) in list1:
            # Swap the values using the original list as source.
            result_list[i],result_list[i+1]=list2[i+1],list2[i]
    return result_list
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a homework problem.

The problem is that you are changing the same list as the one you are iterating through. A first step to the solution, is to loop through list2 and do the changes in list3. That way, the first time you encounter `4`, you swap it towards the right. But then, the next item you encounter in list3 is again `4`, and you swap it again. This keeps on going until you reach the end of list3 with an error trying to swap `4` beyond the end.

But then, another problem occurs: by just setting `list3=list2` you don't really create a new list. Both list3 and list2 are pointing to the same list.

To help seeing what is going on, you can step through your code with the debugger. As this is a rather short code, you can also add `print` statements that show the values of the variables and the list. For example:

```
def swaplist(list1,list2):
    list3=list2
    for i in list3:
        print("i:", i)
        if ('s'+str(i)) in list1:
            a=list3.index(i)
            b=a+1
            list3[a],list3[b]=list3[b],list3[a]
            print('s' + str(i), a, b, "list is now:", list3)
    return list3
```

*** spoiler ***
To really solve your problem, however, you need list3 to be a completely new list. For really complicated structures, you need a deep copy, and there are library function to create such a `deepcopy`. For just a simple list, a copy can be created by iterating again through your list. Or usint the `copy()` function as mentioned by others.

```
def swaplist(list1,list2):
    list3=[i for i in list2]
    for i in list2: # note we are looping through list2 and changing list3
        print("i:", i)
        if ('s'+str(i)) in list1:
            a=list3.index(i)
            b=a+1
            list3[a],list3[b]=list3[b],list3[a]
            print('s' + str(i), a, b, "list is now:", list3)
    return list3
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by JohanC the problem is that you change the list over which you loop.
You can copy first list2 and then only change list3.

```
def swaplist(list1,list2):
    list3=list2.copy()
    for i in list2:
        print(i)
        if f's{i}' in list1:
            a=list3.index(i)
            b=a+1
            list3[a],list3[b]=list3[b],list3[a]
    return list3
```